# Передача значения полей в функцию

Tags: ajax, php, wordpress

Здравствуйте.

У меня возник вопрос, как передать значения полей в функцию.

Есть 2 поля Input с типом Date и один Button, при нажатии которого должны передаться значения полей Input, если они есть, в функцию.

До этого с wordpress практически не работал. Обычно передавал через ajax post-запрос php-скрипту - и дело в шляпе, а тут не могу разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так и передавать через ajax в функцию. 
Ее сперва надо зарегистрировать примерно так:

```
<?php
  add_action('wp_ajax_my_func_handler', 'my_function_name'); // это для админки
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_func_handler', 'my_function_name'); // это надо для фронта
?>
```

Естественно, нужно иметь функцию

```
<?php
my_function_name(){
    // переменная передается ajax'ом их может быть сколько угодно
    $var = (isset($_REQUEST['var'])) ? $_REQUEST['var'] : 'something_if_not';
    ... магия тут
    }
    ?>
```

и js код

```
 var ajaxURL = "http://" + location.host + "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    action = 'my_function_name',
    MY_OTHER_VARS_HERE = '...';

    $.ajax({
      url: ajaxURL,
      data: {
        'action': action,
        'var': MY_OTHER_VARS_HERE 
      },
      beforeSend: function () {
        ...
        }
      },
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.log(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
      }
    });
```

Важно: WP имеет встроенный механизм AJAX в wp-ajax.php - подрубается в JS файле строчкой `ajaxURL = "http://" + location.host + "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"`. Но так делать не совсем правильно (зато быстрее всего и, как правило, проблем в последующем использовании не возникает).

Ваша функция, предварительно зарегистрированная, передается в параметре action js кода

Вроде, все.

**Обновление**

Так: `my_first_func() { my_second_func($_POST['var_1'], $_POST['var_2'])}`?

Если да, то не вижу, что должно мешать этому. Только в данном случае вместо `$_POST` надо `$_REQUEST` написать, хотя на самом деле там `$_GET`.
А если прямо POST обязательно, то в JS параметры вызова ajax добавить тип передачи параметров: `type : "post",`

Comment: Смотри, у меня внутри одной функции выполняется другая, вот второй передать нужно переменные, т.е. чтобы при нажатии сразу выполнилась `name_function($_POST['P1'],$_POST['P2'])`. Так же можно сделать?

Comment: Так? my_first_func() { my_second_func($_POST['var_1'], $_POST['var_2'])}? 
если да, то не вижу, что должно мешать этому. Только в данном случае вместо $_POST надо $_REQUEST написать, хотя на самом деле там $_GET.
А если прямо POST обязательно, то в JS параметры вызова ajax добавить тип передачи параметров: type : "post",